# How to use bootstrap-select with Spring MVC form tags

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I am using [silviomoreto select box plugin](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) in my JSP page along with Spring MVC form tags. While I am able to bind rest of the form fields to the other properties of my entity class I am facing issues in binding the Select box values. I want to dynamically bind the selected options(multiple options are allowed) to a property/field in the Hibernate Entity class.  Can someone please guide me on how to do that? Apart from this I am also getting **JasperException** on putting `<form:select>` tag in my JSP. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my code.

**From JSP**

```
<form:select path="concerns"  class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple data-title='Choose aleast 1 tag'  data-max-options="3">
                      <form:option value="XXX" label="XXX"/>
                      <form:option value="XXX" label="XXX"/>
                      <form:option value="XXX" label="XXX"/>
                      <form:option value="XXX" label="XXX"/>
                      <form:option value="XXX" label="XXX"/>
                    </form:select>
```

**From Entity Class(this uses another entity called concerns)**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="problem")
    public class Problem {
      //other properties here getting binded
      private Set<Concern> concerns;
}
```

**Exception**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp (line: [323], column: [97]) equal symbol expected
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:233) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:169) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:160) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
.
.
```